# Sigma 28-105 3.8 5.6 Lens not sharp with Nikon D7000 unless stopped way down?

Tags: nikon-d7000, sharpness, sigma

I find that my Nikon D7000 is not producing sharp images with a Sigma 28-105mm f/3.8-5.6 lens. It is very soft from f/3.8 - f/11, but from f/13- f/16 it is sharp. But I cannot shoot with these settings in all situations. Would really appreciate any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Please post some sample images - these will help us determine what the problem might me.

Comment: Have you set "AF fine tune" on the D7000 for the lens?

Answer (score 2):

I used to have this kind of problem. Previously I owned Nikon D5000 and it worked superbly with Sigma 17-50 OS. Later, I used the same lens with a Nikon D7100, and most of the time it was out of focus and blurred images resulted. I raised the issue to Sigma and they asked to bring the camera and lens along. They concluded that the lens needed to be re-chipped and calibrated.  Now, I have a very good camera and superb lens.

Comment: @ user28153 - I wish you are correct here..So you are saying that the problem is with lens and the Nikon D7000 body right? I wish this solves my problem.. Thankyou